# Javascript code fails after element is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, reload

I have JS code that counts the number of characters in a textarea. It works once but once the element is reloaded with the updated data it fails with subsequent requests.

```html
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
var counter = function(el,char_el,num_el){
    var cha = el.val().length;
    var num = Math.ceil(cha / 160);
    if(num == 0)
        num = 1;
    char_el.html(cha);
    num_el.html(num);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#TextMsg").keyup(function(){
        counter($(this),$(".char"),$(".num"));
    });
    $("#TextMsg").keyup();
});
</script>

<div id='showsn'>
<textarea id="TextMsg"></textarea>
<p><span class='char'></span>کارکتر</p>
<p><span class='num'></span>پارت</p>
</div>

</body>
```

How can I get the code to work after the element is reloaded?

Comment: So you are saying that you change the value of the `textarea` in code? Where is the code that does that? Is it in an AJAX call?

Comment: No i dont change value of textarea in code. i just reload my div element with ajax by some data like first load in it. <textarea id="TextMsg"></textarea> <p><span class='char'></span>کارکتر</p> <p><span class='num'></span>پارت</p>

Comment: You will need to include the code that updates the `div` via AJAX then.

Comment: After updating you need to call the function again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add event listeners to elements which are destroyed when you update your div content. So events handlers are deleted too !

What you could do is using jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method which allow to add event listener on parent div (which will not be deleted) on a specific selector (your texteara for example). So the event handler will not be destroyed and continue to listen to events after div update.

```
 $('#showsn').on('keyup', '#TextMsg', function () {
    counter($(this), ".char", ".num");
});
```

You can see a working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/royto/pjfcgsx6/

Comment: Thank you so much Dear Julien. it solve my problem. I wish You luck